# Unable to display content on homepage ; Flask app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, flask

I am trying to deploy a flask app on GAE.
All dependencies like Flask, jinja2 etc are in the same directory

When GAE launcher deploys the app locally, it gets deployed but **nothing gets displayed on the home url once the local server is up and running** even though the main.py returns some text for the home url

Following are my files:
**app.yaml**

```
application: texsumm
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: .*
   script: main.app
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def template_test():
     return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

What can be the issue ?

Comment: Where are you defining your "home url" handler?  Anything in the stack trace?

Comment: @GAEfan ,  the line "@app.route("/")" is the home url handler , right ??

Comment: You mentioned both a "home url" and a "base url" (which you said, "returns some text").  If you go to the root domain ("/"), do you see "Hello"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant both base and home to be the same (edited the question).It works fine if I run local server through flask (ie python main.py) and it shows "Hello".  But when I use GAE, it just arrives at the localhost with blank page

Comment: Anything in the app logs?

Comment: raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)                                

HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable  ,   This is the error it shows in the GAE log

Answer (score 0):

try changing main to name:

```
app = Flask("__name__")
```

and

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

 app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask already handles the:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

so delete that.  Read the `run(host=None, port=None, debug=None, **options)` section at:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/